# Postman Generate Code Snippets don't include application protocol type

Tags: http, https, postman

The code snippets generated from postman don't include whether it is HTTP or HTTPS

```
GET/apis/123?api-version=2017-03-01 HTTP/1.1
Host: contoso.anc.net
Content-Type: application/json
If-Match: *
Authorization: Bearer token
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: fe465591-15b3-cbf0-9d9b-f2ed76efcb2c
```

The endpoint contoso.anc.net only responds to https endpoint and one of our customers had to figure out the hard way.

Is this missing information in the snippet or the service side should automatically bump to HTTPS when it gets a request over HTTP? Can somebody point to the spec?

*Edit*

This relates to the `Generate Code Snippets` that can be created within Postman using the `code` button.

[image]

The `HTTP` option:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By using `console.log(pm.request)` in the `Tests` tab you are able to see the request details in the Postman Console. This shows the Protocol as well as the other request data.

[image: Postman]

If the API is not telling you what protocol to use when making requests (In the documentation) or not giving the user any feedback within the response, that seems to me like a different problem your customer is facing.